# How to find the roots of this 4th order polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Can someone explain how to factor/find roots to this 4th order polynomial:

$$ s^4 + 14s^3 +45s^2 +650s + 1800 = 0 $$

It's such a nightmare. I've been stuck for hours, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Use a calculator? I couldn't find a solution by guessing a factor. I checked it on MATLAB and there's pretty much no easy way to factor it.

Comment: use https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+s%5E4%2B14s%5E3%2B45s%5E2%2B650s%2B1800%3D%3D0

Comment: Do not worry! The equation either requires numerical methods or taking quite complicated roots. What is easy to see : The real roots (if existent) must be negative.

Comment: Guess roots: their absolute values should be a divisor of the constant term (1800), or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Those roots can be found algebraically (e.g. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function)), but the procedure is laboursome and error-prone, so that some numerical method (Newton-Raphson, fixed point iteration, secant procedure, ..) might be more practical.

If you manage to guess roots you can reduce the order of the polynomial and end up with easier algebraic solution formulae.

Answer (score 1):

$s^4 + 14s^3 +45s^2 +650s + 1800$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ because it is irreducible mod $11$.

In particular, its roots are irrational numbers.

There is a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) for the roots but it'll probably be very ugly.